# Retrieve Pull Request from Work Item in Azure Devops WebApi

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to programmatically retrieve information of all pull requests associated to a work item in Azure DevOps using Azure DevOps WebAPI.
I have figured out how to retrieve an instance of

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Model.WorkItem
```

For my work item.

To find the pull requests related to it, I can iterate through the Relations field and find a relation where Url contains `PullRequestId`. At the end of that string, I can locate the Pull Request id to be used with the `GetPullRequestAsync`.

The URL might look like this:

```
vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/2139bb34-57e3-4d7d-a6e1-1c0542a45e29%2F8a2b707f-ca7a-418d-8462-2bf076a54aad%2F39723
```

So my code would look like this:

```
foreach ( WorkItemRelation wir in wi.Relations)
{
     if ( wir.Url.Contains("PullRequestId"))
     {
          var pr = build.GetPullRequestAsync("<MyProject>", "Providername", "39723", "repository id").Result;
          // Do somethin with pr object
     }
}
```

My issues with this are the following

1. Parsing the URL to retrieve the Pull Request id does not seem a good way to do this. Can I not get the id from some field or so?
2. `GetPullRequestAsync` requires a provider name and repository id. 
   But should that information not be retrievable from the instance of 
     `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItemRelation`.
3. Is there another easier way of doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of relying on `PullRequestId` I would recommend you use attributes. In URL you will find all what you need:

```cs
var credential = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT");
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/"), credential);
var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

var build = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

var repoClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

var workItem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(1, expand: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result;

foreach (var relation in workItem.Relations)
{
    if((string)relation.Attributes["name"] == "Pull Request")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(relation.Url);

        var segment = relation.Url.Split("/").Last();

        var ids = segment.Split("%2F");

        var repo = repoClient.GetRepositoryAsync(ids[1]).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(repo.Name);

        var pr = build.GetPullRequestAsync(ids[0], "TfsGit", ids[2], ids[1]).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(pr.Title);
        // Do somethin with pr object
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I needed. Is it possible to retrieve the name of the repository given the id? And how come it is so difficult to find documentation on the WebAPI. Code samples are not easily found on the net

Comment: Yes. It is possible. I added this to above written code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no other better way to achieve this. The currently known method is to retrieve the pull request id from the url.

From the response you can retrieve the relations with the `"name": "Pull Request"`. Then you can split the url string with `%2F`, the pull request id is the last part.

Regarding the second issue, you can use this [Get Pull Request By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api to get the pull request detailed information. Just need to provide pull request id in the request.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.1
```